# how to alter a table to combine two rows that are the same and add the qty column up

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I need to alter a table to combine 2 rows if they are the same and have it add the qty column together. I don't want to create a new table just alter the one that's there for example if I have a row that is:

| Account | Name | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | John | Red Shoe | 1 |
| 123 | John | Red Shoe | 1 |

How would I alter the table to combine the two rows to be:

| Account | Name | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | John | Red Shoe | 2 |

I cannot find the answer to this kind of question anywhere online.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: What should "alter the table" mean? Are you looking for an insert? Or do you want to show it in a query only? Alter the table would mean changing their columns and this seems not to be intended?

Comment: @RobinBastiaan i am running mysql community on aws

Comment: You're having a hard time managing to handle this situation because you don't have unique identifiers (a simple auto-increment integer for example). Adding such kind of field as part of your database/tables design would help you considerably carrying out most sql operations, and would make this kind of problem way more smooth than how it is now.

Comment: @lemon i do have unique identifiers. your response to my question does not do anything and has nothing to do with what i asked lol. how would unique identifiers change my situation of combining these two rows?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you are asking for. Alter Table is not appropriate and there is no mysql function which can combine rows or any statement which could insert new rows and delete other rows - you would need an insert followed by a delete..but the delete would have to know what to delete and it's not obvious from your question how this could be achieved

```
DROP table if exists t;
create table t
(Account    int,Name varchar(20),   Item    varchar(20) ,Qty int);
insert into t values
(123    ,'John' ,'Red Shoe' ,1),
(123    ,'John' ,'Red Shoe' ,1);

#select * from t;

insert into t 
    select account,name,item,sum(qty)
    from t
    group by account,name,item;
    
select * from t; 

---------+------+----------+------+
| Account | Name | Item     | Qty  |
+---------+------+----------+------+
|     123 | John | Red Shoe |    1 |
|     123 | John | Red Shoe |    1 |
|     123 | John | Red Shoe |    2 |
+---------+------+----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```